# Bash - shell script fail to open file on 2nd iteration

Tags: bash, shell

Why on 2nd iteration this loop do not see file `repos_filtered_blob.json` even it is still there? My script do not modify that file after creation and after first iteration that si fine send iteration fail as it is not able too access file.

```bash
while [ $REPOS_COUNT -gt 0 ]

do

    echo "Getting the repo name to be deployed..."

    REPO_NAME=$( jq -r .[$i].Name repos_filtered_blob.json)

    echo "Repository name: $REPO_NAME"


    echo "Checking if the repo should be deployed to $ENVIRONMENT environment..."
    echo "$ENVIRONMENT environment detected! Extracting the source branch name..."

    BRANCH_NAME=$(less repos_filtered_blob.json | jq -r '.['$i'].BRANCH')
    echo "Source branch name: $BRANCH_NAME"
    REPO_LINK=$( jq -r .[$i].Link repos_filtered_blob.json)



    echo "Repository LINK: $REPO_LINK"
    ADJUSTED_LINK=$(echo $REPO_LINK | sed "s,https://.*@,https://$TOKEN@,g")
    echo "Adjusted link: $ADJUSTED_LINK"
    REPO_SSH=$( jq -r .[$i].SSH repos_filtered_blob.json)

    echo ""
    CONTAINER_NAME=$( jq -r .[$i].PATH repos_filtered_blob.json)
    echo "Container name: $CONTAINER_NAME"

    echo "Cloning the source branch..."

    rm -rf $REPO_NAME
    git clone --branch $BRANCH_NAME --single-branch https://$TOKEN@dev.azure.com/sonova-retail${ADJUSTED_LINK#https://sonova-retail.visualstudio.com}



    echo "Checking if the repository had recent commits..."
    cd $REPO_NAME

    if git log --date=relative --since "2 months ago" | grep -q commit; 
    then
        echo "Repository edited recently, will proceed with copying..."
        cd ..
        echo "Saving the list of the contents..."
        ls $REPO_NAME/ > contents.txt
        cat contents.txt
        echo "Deleting the pre-existing folders from the container..."
        az storage blob delete-batch --auth-mode login --account-name $STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME -s $CONTAINER_NAME
        ./azcopy rm "https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$CONTAINER_NAME" --recursive=true --list-of-files=contents.txt
        
        
        if [ "$REPO_NAME" = "DIF-SO-data-governance" ];
        then
            echo "Checking which env folder can be deleted from DIF_data_governance"
            ENVIRONMENT_FOLDERS=$(ls ../../DIF-SO-data-governance/$ENVIRONMENT/data_ingestion_framework/)
            TO_DELETE=("${ENVIRONMENT_FOLDERS[@]/$ENVIRONMENT}")
            for FOLDER in ${TO_DELETE[@]}
            do
                echo "Removing: $FOLDER from $REPO_NAME"
                rm -r DIF-SO-data-governance/$ENVIRONMENT/data_ingestion_framework/$FOLDER
            done
    fi
    echo ""
    echo "Copying the files to the container..."
    ./azcopy cp "$REPO_NAME/$ENVIRONMENT/*" "https://$STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/$CONTAINER_NAME" --recursive=true --disable-auto-decoding=true --exclude-path  ".git"

    else echo "Environment $ENVIRONMENT not detected! Skipping..."
            echo "";
    fi
    ((i=i+1))
    ((REPOS_COUNT=REPOS_COUNT-1))


done
```

1st itertrion

```
Getting the repo name to be deployed...
repos_filtered_blob.json
Repository name: DIF-SO-data-governance-test-cases
Checking if the repo should be deployed to CH-SO-BIA-DATAHUB-PL-UK environment...
CH-SO-BIA-DATAHUB-PL-UK environment detected! Extracting the source branch name...
Source branch name: develop
```

2nd iteration

```
Getting the repo name to be deployed...
ls: cannot access 'repos_filtered_blob.json': No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file repos_filtered_blob.json: No such file or directory
Repository name:
Checking if the repo should be deployed to CH-SO-BIA-DATAHUB-PL-UK environment...
CH-SO-BIA-DATAHUB-PL-UK environment detected! Extracting the source branch name...
repos_filtered_blob.json: No such file or directory
Source branch name:
jq: error: Could not open file repos_filtered_blob.json: No such file or directory
Repository LINK:
Adjusted link:
jq: error: Could not open file repos_filtered_blob.json: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file repos_filtered_blob.json: No such file or directory
Container name:
```

Is there a possibility that `less` is creating some kind file lock?

Comment: is it possible after `cd $REPO_NAME`, it doesn't have chance to `cd ..` in first iteration?

Comment: Brilliant! It's shame that i didn't thinked about such simple cause. Yes. That is the issue.

Comment: You could probably also just use relative pathing the way you did in the `azcopy`, and never use `cd`.  To each his own.